# calculating money after 365 days if payment increased $5 per day

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How much money would you have if the amount of money you started with was 5 and it increased by 5 a day for 365 days.
So January 1st you receive 5, Jan 2nd you receive 10, the third 15.. etc.
I'm wondering what the formula is

Comment: This is certainly a duplicate, but I can't find the original.

Comment: I'd imagine but, if I could find the original I wouldn't have posted it :[

Comment: That is a good point!  For future reference, what you have here is called an "arithmetic series."  (Adding up the terms of an arithmetic progression)

Comment: There is, as is all too often the case, some ambiguity in the question. If you increase by $5$ for $365$ days, and start at $5$, then a possible interpretation is that you are paid for $366$ days.  However, the question poser probably *meant* Jan. 1 through Dec. $31$ in a non-leap year.  Then the posted calculations are of course right.

Comment: Try [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/59443/6179).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**
On the 365th day, you will receive $365*5=1825$ dollars.  Then the total amount of money is

$$5+10+15+\cdots+1820+1825.$$  Consider double this amount.  That is consider $$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
5 & +10 & +15 & +\cdots & +1815 & +1820 & +1825\\
1825 & +1820 & +1815 & +\cdots & +15 & +10 & +5\end{array}$$

Adding up the rows we get $$1830+1830+1830+\cdots+1830+1830+1830$$

$$=365*1830.$$  Now take this and divide it by 2.  Then we have the original sum.

See also:  [Arithmetic Progression.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 3):

$$5 + 2\times 5 + 3\times 5 + \cdots + 365\times 5 = 5\times\Bigl( 1+2+\cdots + 365\Bigr)$$
at which point it comes down to figuring out how much is the sum of $n$ consecutive integers, starting with $1$.